# How to find people to do long hikes?

Tags: online-resources, hiking, mountain-climbing, self-guided

I'm hoping to do the summit climb at Gunung Mulu National Park. Unfortunately, a guide is required, and there's a 3-person minimum. Since only 30-40 people do this climb every year, just showing up at park headquarters and hoping for the best is *probably* not going to work.

What resources are available for finding other people to do these sort of long, guided hikes?

Comment: Could you just keep hiring guides until you make the minimum group size (expensive, I know)?

Comment: This particular hike requires advanced booking, and getting to the national park actually involves a plane trip. And I'm not made of money since I've quit my job and am on a "round the world" tour at the moment. :) I'm really looking forward to general resources because my plan involves doing Mt Kinabalu next, then a bunch of volcanoes in Indonesia.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility you have is to find a hiking club. There are some all over the world and that's where you'll probably find the most involved hikers, those ready to invest money on long hiking trips, far from home. Most of these clubs have online forums or some sort of ad board where people would post any climbing partner search ad. They also organise these long hiking trips.

The problem is still that the trip you seem to have in mind requires a lot of preparation and money, so planning it several months in advance is probably required.

I know there are a lot of club sections part of the [French Alpine Club](http://www.ffcam.fr/), but they do not really communicate together for forming teams. There is also a [Alpine Club of Canada](http://www.alpineclubofcanada.ca/) and I found that the American Alpine Club has a ["Member Share" program](http://m.americanalpineclub.org/clubhouse/membershare/) whose purpose is exactly to find a climbing partner.

You should try to contact one of these clubs and see if they have such climbing partner ad board, or organise such trips.

Contacting directly the national park to ask if hiking clubs organise such trips might also work.

Comment: "Local" as in Indonesian or from the OP's country of origin? I think you mean the latter, which is a good idea, but I can't tell from your answer.